# how to insert the same value from listbox to database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, listbox

how to insert without changing the value from the list box to the database 
i have 3 list-boxes and a table in the database , the code...

```
private void Order()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString1))
        {
            String query = "INSERT INTO Tbl_order (OrderName,Quantity,Price,Serves_way,Date) VALUES (@OrderName,@Quantity, @Price,'"+servers+"','" + time1.ToString(format1)+"' )";


                connection.Open();

                for (int i = 0; i < lst_OrderName.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add("OrderName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lst_OrderName.GetItemText(lst_OrderName.GetSelected(i));
                        command.Parameters.Add("Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(lst_QTY.GetSelected(i));
                        command.Parameters.Add("Price", SqlDbType.Money).Value = Convert.ToDouble(lst_Price2.GetSelected(i));

                       /* command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderName", lst_OrderName.GetItemText(lst_OrderName.Items));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", lst_QTY.GetItemText(lst_QTY.Items));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", lst_Price2.GetItemText(lst_Price2.Items));*/

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }  

        }
    }
```

**So the 3 list boxes like this with value string , int and double**

[image]

**and the inserted values in the database like this**

[image]

As you see they are not the same values as list-boxes values

**how to insert the same value from listbox to database ?**

Comment: GetSelected returns the row selected not any row of your listboxes

Comment: yeap i wanna know how to insert them all to the database without selecting them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a prepared query. You prepare the query by adding the parameters and their data-type, the length of the column is optional. Then call `Prepare()`. After that you assign the data to the parameters by index or by column name and finally calling `ExecuteNonQuery`

```
private void Order()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString1))
    {
        String query = "INSERT INTO Tbl_order (OrderName,Quantity,Price,Serves_way,Date) VALUES (@OrderName,@Quantity, @Price,'"+servers+"','" + time1.ToString(format1)+"' )";


        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            // Add the length of this text column as third parameter...
            command.Parameters.Add("OrderName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("Quantity", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters.Add("Price", SqlDbType.Money);
            command.Prepare();

            for (int i = 0; i < lst_OrderName.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                // Dont know if the .ToString() calls are necessary...
                command.Parameters[0].Value = lst_OrderName.GetItemText(lst_OrderName.Items[i].ToString());
                command.Parameters[1].Value = Convert.ToInt32(lst_QTY.Items[i].ToString());
                command.Parameters[2].Value = Convert.ToDouble(lst_Price2.Items[i].ToString());
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }  

    }
}
```

EDIT:
Updated the answer to get the items correctly from each ListBox (as Steve already mentioned)

Comment: hello ^^ i've tried it but still gave the same inserted value problem in the database i dont know what is wrong .

Comment: @MaxThunder Answer updated. You get the Items by accessing the `.Items` property of the ListBox, specifying the row-index in `[` and `]`. The returned value is always an object, so you might have to cast or convert it to the type you need.

Comment: it works , i'm so happy haha thanks a lot really ^^ thanks.